# How get only one line from the response at server android

Tags: java, android, html, request, response

I have some problem with get one line. I need to get one line of the server's response, if it is then the registration fails, if it does not then all is well.Here is a piece of code where I get the response from the server after a request:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
                    "http://guiddy.fosslabs.ru/users/sign_in");
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
            response = client.execute(post);
            String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

            Log.d("POST", "Response " + responseStr);
```

And there my response:

```
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220): <html>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):   <head>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):     <title>KFU Guide</title>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):     <link href="/assets/application-322e6975fe46a0c54a3827debe6d5726.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):     <script src="/assets/application-803c643ca444e7c5678978757763fb7e.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):     <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220): <meta content="uN8Hb2qA2nBr1euV6xKh4l8PGQYyzYviH5Ba5Ncwl24=" name="csrf-token" />
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):     <!--[if lt IE 9]>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220): <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220): <![endif]-->
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):   </head>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):   <body>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):     <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):   <div class="navbar-inner">
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):     <div class="row">
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):       <a href="/home" id="logo">KFU Guide</a>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):       <nav>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):         <ul class="nav pull-right">
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):           <div class="exit">
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):             <a href="/users/sign_in">Вход</a> |
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):             <a href="/users/sign_up">Зарегистрироваться</a>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):         </div>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):         </ul>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):       </nav>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):     </div>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):    
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):     <div class="space">  
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):           <nav>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):              <ul class="nav pull-left">
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):               <li><a href="/rooms">Аудитории</a></li>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):               <li><a href="/events">События</a></li>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):               <li><a href="/find_empty_room">Поиск свободной аудитории</a></li>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):             </ul>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):           </nav> 
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):     </div>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):   
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):   </div>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220): </header>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):     <br>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):     <br>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):     <div class="container">
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):         <div class="alert alert-alert"> Invalid email or password. </div>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):       <h1>Вход в систему</h1>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220): <div class="row">
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):   <div class="span6 offset3">
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):     <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/sessions/user" class="new_user" id="new_user" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="uN8Hb2qA2nBr1euV6xKh4l8PGQYyzYviH5Ba5Ncwl24=" /></div>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):       <label for="user_email">Email</label>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):       <input autofocus="autofocus" id="user_email" name="user[email]" size="30" type="email" value="deniknovik@gmail.com" />
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):       <label for="user_password">Password</label>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):       <input id="user_password" name="user[password]" size="30" type="password" />
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):         <input name="user[remember_me]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="user_remember_me" name="user[remember_me]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):         <label for="user_remember_me">Remember me</label>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):       <div class="center">
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):         <input class="btn btn-large btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="Войти" />
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):         <br>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):         <br>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):         <a href="/users/auth/facebook" class="services"><img alt="Facebook" height="32" src="/assets/fb-438d0240ee7e9ca267a8b8b0c984f531.png" width="32" /></a>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):         <a href="/users/auth/twitter" class="services"><img alt="Facebook" height="34" src="/assets/tw-f3aa14c332eace82e49dc3776b3ec8cc.png" width="34" /></a>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):         <a href="/users/auth/vkontakte" class="services"><img alt="Facebook" height="32" src="/assets/vk-d772cd8b00aa8f4a0ec821ca6aa649bc.png" width="32" /></a>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):       </div>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):       
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):   <a href="/users/sign_up">Sign up</a><br />
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):   <a href="/users/password/new">Forgot your password?</a><br />
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220): </form>  </div>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220): </div>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):  
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):     </div>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220):   </body>
09-17 13:47:49.556: D/POST(3220): </html>
```

And I need get only this line:

```
<div class="alert alert-alert"> Invalid email or password. </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to the problem, I used Jsoup. I received the following example:

```
String str3 = null;
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(responseStr);
Elements elems = doc.select("div");
for (Element elem : elems) {
    if (elem.attr("class").equals("alert alert-alert")) {
        str3 = elem.text();
    }
}
Log.d("POST", "Response " + responseStr);
Log.d("POST2", "Response " + str3);
Log.d("POST1", "Response "
+ response.getStatusLine().toString());
```

Then do the processing of the data